# How can I get the value from a Form::select in javascript / Laravel blades

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to get the selected value from a Form::select in a blade's javascript file.

This is my blade:

```
{!!Form::open(['route' => [$complete == true ? 'completeAnalytical.store' : 'analytical.store'], 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'multiparametricAnalyticalForm'])!!}

{!! Form::select('fluid_type',['1' => 'Oil', '2' => 'Gas'], null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'fluid_type']) !!}
            
{!! Form::submit('Run' , array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'save')) !!}
```

This is the JS of my blade:

```
function myFunction() {
     var myVar = $("input[name = fluid_type]").val();
     console.log(myVar);
}
```

This is the console answer:

```
undefined
```

Is there any way to get the selected value ?
Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to select the element by the `id` you've set for it.

**Change the selector to**

```
$("#fluid_type").val()
```

**With your code**

```
function myFunction() {
    var myVar = $("#fluid_type").val();
    console.log(myVar);
}
```

[More information](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)